Optimal way to create a dataframe from an SQL query
I'm looking to find a more efficient way to execute SQL queries within Python. My current process seems optimal when running the query, however the conversion process to a data frame appears to be inefficient given the execution times.
Below is is a rough framework of my code. I apologize for not providing a fully reproducible example, as a connection to Oracle is needed.
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import time

login_info = f"""

    Driver={{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - IBMDBCL1}};
    HostName=xxx;
    Port=xxx;
    Security=xxx;
    Database=xxx;
    UID={xxx};
    PWD={xxx};
"""

conn = pyodbc.connect(login_info)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def execute_sql(query):
    query_start_time = time.time()
    cursor.execute(query)

    cols = [c[0] for c in cursor.description]
    cols = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), cols))

    query_rt = "--- Query Runtime: %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - query_start_time)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=cols)

    total_rt = "--- Total Runtime: %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - query_start_time)
    
    print(query_rt)
    print(total_rt)
    return df

loss_query = '''

select * from xxx limit 1

'''

loss_df = execute_sql(loss_query)

When running my query that is not specified, the Query Runtime = 99 seconds and the Total Runtime = 359 seconds. It seems odd to me that converting the cursor to a dataframe takes 2.6x longer than it takes to execute the query, but maybe that's standard?

Are you familiar with pandas.read_sql_query()? I'm not sure if it's faster offhand, but it does eliminate the need to run the query and create the DataFrame separately. Here are the docs.

It's not standard. Consider what your code is doing. cursor.fetchall() is loading all results in memory and only when that finishes does it try to create a dataframe. read_sql_query on the other hand processes rows as they arrive from the database. Processing rows one by one isn't very efficient, so chunksize is used to tell Pandas how many rows to retrieve before processing them
